# Re-Balncing disks within a Datanode in Apache Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a Apache Hadoop Cluster. One of the node faced with skewed data distribution. The machine has 3 disks. disk 1 occupied around 86% , Disk 2 30% and Disk 3 60% respectively. Now, what to do if data is unevenly distributed among the disks within a DataNode? 
P.S: I would like to inform you that the Storage Type is NOT same, so, I am not able to follow HDFS-1312. Also, my Hadoop version is 2.5.0.
any help? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intranode balancer was introduced in Hadoop3.

I'm not sure there is an alternative without moving around files yourself, which might be risky even though it think the namenode only tracks the datanode, not data volumes